# Bell-LaPadula model and composite services

Tags: access-control, web-service, bell-lapadula

The Bell-LaPadula model is useful for access control. Can I use this model for access control in composite services?

The security level of each service is exported from WS_SecurityPolicy file.

Answer (score 1):

according to bellow mentioned paper, Bell-Lapadula Model is not compatible with Composite services:

**Incompatible Access Control Models:** Access control of a composition is dependent on the access control capabilities of the individual services. Where different component services use different access control models, the result could be a violation of any of the models. As a simple example, consider a travel assistance service composition where the POI service applies **BellLaPadula** (“no read up, no write down” for confidentiality), while the route service applies **Biba** (“no read down, no write up” for integrity), is liable to result in a confused system with both models partially implemented.

[Security and Trustworthiness Threats to Composite Services: Taxonomy, Countermeasures, and Research Directions](https://vpn.utm.my/web/1/http/0/link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-13518-2_2) springer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If we use the blp model in all component services,then can we use this idea?we can assume that each service is a subject,then according the ws_security policy,we can intriduce  security level for each service And implement the blp model.is this idea correct?please help me.